# How to let elasticsearch coordinate node don't merge and resort

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, the ES cluster has 3 shards, a query wants to get 300 docs.

Normally, the coordinate node will get 300 docs from each shard, that's 3*300=900 docs in total, then coordinate node sort these 900 docs and return top 300 docs.

How can I set the query, let coordinate node get 100 docs from each shard and return 3*100=300 docs?

Answer (score 0):

Am curious why you would like every single shard to only return an equally sized share/slice of the resulting hits, as it is very unlikely that the 300 most relevant/important hits are evenly distributed across all shards.

The coordinating node's task is not just to return 300 hits, but the 300 most relevant/important hits. By default hits are sorted by descending score (unless you specify a different sorting criteria). Statically considering 100 hits from every single shard could result in a total meaningless result list.

An example: for simplicity, assume that your index is only made up of 2 (primary) shards and you contains documents about mobile phone news back in early 2007. It's very likely that you have many documents in your index about Windows, Nokia and Blackberry phones. And then, all of a sudden the iPhone got announced and articles start popping up. Let's further assume that short ofter the presentation of the phone there have been 100 very relevant articles about iPhones been published and indexed in your Elasticsearch index and now you are querying for the best 100 hits about iPhones. With coordinating nodes "optimized" the way you are asking for, the first fifty documents would get retrieved from both shards. As a consequence it will be very likely that you only end up having something like 60-70 of the relevant articles in your result set, and the other 30-40 very relevant hits are missing (and even worse, 30-40 articles are rather irrelevant and just made it in, because they mentioned the term iPhone once).

Actually, the coordinating nodes are also "smart" and under certain conditions can skip shards when it's guaranteed that they they don't contain any matching document.

Furthermore, if you don't deal with big data and all your documents easily fix into a single, configure your index to be made up of 1 shard and the coordinating node does not need to do any merging.

If your use-case does not rely on relevancy at all, you could think of organizing your data in different indices (rather than multiple shards within an index). Then you can query every single index independently for the first n hits, and merge the results on application side. But as this involves more network roundtrips, it eventually might be even slower.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your explanation, your concern won't happen in my business. I stored merchants in ES, my service retrieve the nearest N merchants from ES then resort them by other parameters, and I checked the data its distribution is uniform.